# Google OAuth2 response_type error on authorization code request

Tags: javascript, oauth, authorization, google-oauth

I'm trying to get an **authorization code** from Google+ API, as described in [Step 1(Set authorization parameters)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) (HTTP/REST).

As I've read there, the Google authorization server has the following mandatory query string parameters: *client_id*, *redirect_uri* and *scope*, so my href would look like this:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=123002756467-dmq0soo7rlfc4on640hdsehnrvb700t7.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000/oAuthCallback&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.location`

When trying to access that link, I get the following error:
**Error: invalid_request (Required parameter is missing: response_type)**

Though, the *response_type* parameter is not specified in that parameter list at all!

Any ideas how this can be solved?

> **Fixed**. It seems that the spaces in my code editor were also inserted in my link as "%20", so that's why it didn't work.

Comment: check the OAuth2 response type: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-3.1.1

Comment: @Edwin, even after specifying the response_type parameter, I do get the same error

Comment: in step2 you have `response_type` specified + other params, have you tried that ones?

Comment: response_type=code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're following the server documentation, the response_type=code parameter is present in the sample authorization request URL in the next step [1].

You can learn more about response types here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#response-type

[1] https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#redirecting